# Show a filtered document library from Sharepoint site to another site (same intranet)

Tags: sharepoint-online, kql

I'm trying to design a site in our intranet to show documents related to our department. I want to show documents in libraries/folders/lists from the main site on our site and be able to filter them depending on the Properties (columns in the libraries/folders/lists) they are defined with (for example "Process", "Document Type" & "Target Group").
I try to use a Higlighted Content web part and write a query with KQL. However i cannot access them as i hoped, for example:

```
Process: "Standards"
```

I've read that they must be Queryable and such, but how do i find that out? I have no admin access to the main site and cant seem to find the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to specify a valid managed property name for the property restriction.

If the property "Process" is a crawled property value, you need to ask your administrator to first map the crawled property to a managed property.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#specifying-property-names-for-property-restrictions

Comment: Is there a way to see if it is a managed property without the admin rights?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, ways to view crawled properties and managed properties: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#view-crawled-properties-and-managed-properties